# redirect to a wildcard subdomain with htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I already added a subdomain wildcard to my dns (*.domain.com) but now i can't get the rule right.

I want

```
subdomain.domain.com
```

to point to

```
domain.com/subdomain
```

my htaccess file is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_OST} ^(?:www\.)?((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.%2/%1 [R=302,L]
```

but i'm getting Internal Server Error. 
How can i get it to work ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to actually redirect then you can do this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/subdomain/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you don't want it to redirect and keep subdomain.example.com in the address bar then, you can do this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This cannot work as OP actually wants it dynamic meaning. Any value can be before `example.com`